# Jira REST API to MySQL request

Tags: mysql, jira-rest-api

Is it possible to get data through REST API from Jira directly to mysql without using rest client in Java/Python etc?

I need to get and regularly update data from there to my database.

Comment: so you're asking "how do I eat pizza without putting pizza in my mouth"? If you want data from a REST API, how exactly do you propose do that without using the API in the first place?

Comment: @MarcB the whole idea is to use api using only sql scripts if it possible at all

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to say no but I could be wrong. You're looking for the ability of mysql to run something like PHP, java, python, vb that could access another server and pass the results to a SQL script.

However, even if you could do it, I don't think it's a very good idea because there is probably more complexity to the problem than you envision right now. There will be issues of outages, backups, picking up where you left off, changing current issues when status changes, new comments, etc. The only way to guarantee synchronization is to dump the jira database and load it completely into your database, something a REST API isn't really intended to do. If you have access to the JIRA system, just ask them for a database dump. If your using someone else jira system, they probably won't appreciate the load you will place on their API and will shut you out.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't have access to DB anyhow. Obtaining access would definitely solve the issue but that is not possible. There is also possibility to get XML dump of Jira (!= DB Dump in XML) trough admin panel and try to restore it on Jira installed locally but i have failed to do that. So the only option left is to get it through REST API. I can write script for requests needed but i was wondering perhaps there is possibility to do that from SQL directly. Yep i know that it is sounds pervert. But in my previous employment place people made magic using SQL.

Comment: An XML dump would be pretty good though. A lot of XML can be read in POJO's quickly and used to reload the database.